# How do I increase the position of a letter in a list by the position of letter?

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

I have a program that takes the position of a letter and increases the position by the value of the shift and then gives me the new position of the letters, it's a caesar list function. However i need to be able to increase the position of the letter by the value of shift and also by the position of the letter, so if i have "hello" and shift is 15, h = 7 so 7 +15 +0 = 22 and e would be 4+15+1(position of e) = 20
However, I'm not sure how to edit my code so that I can increase the position of each letter by the value of their position. The code works fine, I just need help figuring out this step.

```
alphabet =['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'] 
def caesar(plaintext,shift):  
# initialize ciphertext as blank string
    ciphertext = ""
# loop through the length of the plaintext
    for i in range(len(plaintext)):        
    # get the ith letter from the plaintext
        letter = plaintext[i]
    # find the number position of the ith letter
        num_in_alphabet = alphabet.index(letter)
        print (num_in_alphabet)
    # find the number position of the cipher by adding the shift 
        cipher_num = (num_in_alphabet + shift + 3) % len(alphabet) 
    # find the cipher letter for the cipher number you computed
        cipher_letter = alphabet[cipher_num] 
    # add the cipher letter to the ciphertext
        ciphertext = ciphertext + cipher_letter 

# return the computed ciphertext
    return ciphertext
def main():

    plaintext = ("hello")
    shift = 16

    text = caesar(plaintext,shift)
    print (text)

main()
```

Comment: On every iteration add `i` to your letter

Comment: i tried adding i after every iteration but i keep getting an error message. Says that i is not an int value.

Comment: You can create a local var `pos=0` add it and increment it every loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
cipher_num = (num_in_alphabet + shift + i) % len(alphabet)
```

Or much simpler

```
shift = 16
chiper =  ''.join([chr(((ord(c)-ord('a')+shift+i)%26)+ord('a')) for i, c in enumerate("hellow")])
assert  chiper == 'xvdeir'
```

Comment: I tried using that however it gives me back the wrong output. For ex: if my shift key is 16 then my output for "hello" should be: "xvdei". however trying out this gave me : ayghl

Comment: that is because you are adding `3`  ie  it should be `(num_in_alphabet + shift + i)` not `(num_in_alphabet + shift + 3 + i)`

Comment: omg thank you! i tried earlier and i kept getting error coded and now it works!